Solve coupled ODEs with NDSolve
I have a system of coupled ODEs
\begin{align}\label{eq:mu_soliton_param}
    \dot{\mu} &= -8\epsilon \sinh^{3}\mu \sin k \cos k \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}{\cosh\mu(n+1-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-1-x_0)}\Big(1+\frac{\sinh^{2}\mu}{\cosh_0^{2}}\Big)\Big ( \frac{\sinh_0}{\cosh_2 \cosh_{-2}}\Big ),
\end{align}
\begin{align}\label{eq:x0_soliton_param}
    \dot{x}_0 &= \frac{2}{\mu}\sinh \mu \sin k - \frac{8}{\epsilon}\cosh\mu \sinh^{3}\mu\sin k \cos k\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(n-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}{\cosh\mu(n+1-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-1-x_0)}\Big(1+\frac{\sinh^{2}\mu}{\cosh_0^{2}}\Big)\Big ( \frac{\sinh_0}{\cosh_2 \cosh_{-2}}\Big )
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \dot{k} &= -2\epsilon \sinh^{2}\mu (1+\sinh^{2}\mu)(1+\sin^{2}k)\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\tanh\mu(n-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-x_0)}{\cosh\mu(n+1-x_0)\cosh\mu(n-1-x_0)}\Big ( 1+\frac{\sinh^{2}\mu}{\cosh_0^{2}}\Big)\Big ( \frac{\cosh_0}{\cosh_2 \cosh_{-2}}\Big )
\end{align}
where $ch_{\pm m} := \cosh(\mu (n \pm m - x_0))$ (resp $sh_{\pm m}$)
I am interested in plotting the values $(\mu,k)$ for which $x_0 = 0$. To do that, I arbitrarily truncate the sums in the above equations, and use NDSolve:
x = 0;
\[Epsilon] = 1/2^(1 + 2);


sol = NDSolve[{\[Mu]'[
      t] - (-8 \[Epsilon] (Sinh[\[Mu][t]])^3 Sin[k[t]] Cos[k[t]] Sum[
        Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)]/(
         Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 1 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - 1 - x)]) (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu][
              t]])^2/(Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)])^2) (Sinh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - x)]/(
          Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 2 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
              t]*(n - 2 - x)])), {n, -10, 10}]) == 0,
   k'[t] - (-2 \[Epsilon] (Sinh[\[Mu][
          t]])^2 (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu][t]])^2) (1 + (Sin[k[t]])^2) Sum[(
         Tanh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)])/(
         Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 1 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - 1 - x)]) (1 + (Sinh[\[Mu][
              t]])^2/(Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n - x)])^2) (Cosh[\[Mu][
             t]*(n - x)]/(
          Cosh[\[Mu][t]*(n + 2 - x)] Cosh[\[Mu][
              t]*(n - 2 - x)])), {n, -10, 10}]) == 0, \[Mu][0] == 1, 
   k[0] == 0.05}, {\[Mu], k}, {t, 0, 50}]

However, the solution returned is $\mu(t)=1$ and $k(t)=0.05$, which are the given initial conditions. Why does NDSolve think these constant functions are the solutions?

Sinh[\[Mu][ t]*(n - x)]  is an odd function of n for $x=0$, that is why.

@yarchik Ah, indeed. This technically Answers my question since the summands cancel each other out. I am unsure how to visually show the terms cancelling, but if you can do this and submit it as an Answer I will accept it.

You can define summands:
sumMu[n_]:=Cosh[n μ[t]] Sech[(n-2) μ[t]] Sech[(n-1) μ[t]] Sech[(1+n) μ[t]] Sech[(2+n) μ[t]] (1+Sech[n μ[t]]2 Sinh[μ[t]]2) Sinh[n μ[t]]
sumK[n_]:= Cosh[n μ[t]] Sech[(n-2) μ[t]] Sech[(n-1) μ[t]] Sech[(1+n) μ[t]] Sech[(2+n) μ[t]] (1+Sech[n μ[t]]2 Sinh[μ[t]]2) Sinh[n μ[t]]

so that equations look like
sol=NDSolve[{
  μ'[t]-(-8 ϵ (Sinh[μ[t]])^3 Sin[k[t]] Cos[k[t]]
   Sum[sumMu[n],{n,-10,10}] )==0,
  k'[t]-(-2 ϵ (Sinh[μ[t]])^2 (1+(Sinh[μ[t]])^2) (1+(Sin[k[t]])^2)
   Sum[sumK[n],{n,-10,10}])==0,
  μ[0]==1, k[0]==0.05}, {μ, k}, {t,0,50}]

Now you can check
sumMu[n] + sumMu[-n] // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
sumK[n] + sumK[-n] // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)

Additionally you can check that sumMu[0]==sumK[0]==0.
